# VSCode auto imports broke since adding absolute imports (NextJS + Typescript project)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, auto-import

One of the NextJS projects I've been working on recently has become complex and some of the file import paths were looking extremely messy, i.e. `import { AuthHelper } from '../../../lib/auth`

I decided to use [absolute imports](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases) to get around this, so my imports now look like `import { AuthHelper } from '@/lib/auth'`.

Since changing my `tsconfig` auto imports have broken inside of my `VSCode` and `nvim` setups.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I've tried changing `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"` to both `non-relative` and `auto` but auto importing still doesn't work.

Am I missing anything else?

Comment: did you figured out what was happening? having the same problem

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't :( I had to use relative imports.